# How to avoid converting among different 'string' types in haskell, using snapframework?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, haskell-snap-framework

I want to produce the decoded result for POST data. Much code is 'wasted' in converting 'string'. That makes code ugly. Any better solutions?

```
import           Codec.Binary.Url (decode')
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L (unpack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as S (unpack, pack)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS (pack)

decodeUrlHandler :: Snap()
decodeUrlHandler = do
    body <- readRequestBody (maxBound :: Int64)
    writeLBS $ LBS.pack $ map (fromMaybe 0) $ decode' $ L.unpack body
```

What would your code for this purpose be?

Comment: Maybe add my own function `fromMaybeW8sToLBS = LBS.pack . map (fromMaybe 0)`

Comment: Why do you need to decode the request body yourself? Are you sure that Snap doesn't do that for you?

Comment: @nponeccop, request body has type ByteString, I want regard it as url encoded string and decode it. But decode' (url decode) want String and returns [Maybe Word8].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Snap automatically decodes the request and makes it available to you through the [Request](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.6.0.1/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#t%3aRequest) data type.  It provides functions [getRequest](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.6.0.1/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#v%3agetRequest) and [withRequest](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.6.0.1/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#v%3awithRequest) for retrieving the request and a number of other accessor functions for getting various parts.

There are also convenience functions for common operations.  To get a POST or GET parameter see [getParam](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.6.0.1/doc/html/Snap-Core.html#v%3agetParam).

Snap gives it to you as a ByteString because this API sits at a fairly low level of abstraction, leaving it up to the user how to handle things like text encoding.  I would recommend that you use the much more efficient Text type instead of String.  The [Readable](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/snap-core/0.6.0.1/doc/html/Snap-Util-Readable.html) type class also provides a mechanism for eliminating some of the boilerplate of these conversions.  The default instances for numbers and Text assume UTF8 encoding.

Comment: I second the suggestion to use Data.Text along with {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-} if you aren't already.  You might also find that you have to 'import Data.String (IsString)' for some conversions, but Snap makes this pretty straightforward.

Comment: If I use Text type, I need an extra convertion to apply some functions that accept String type, Codec.Binary.Url.decode' in this case.

Comment: The fromBS function provided by the Readable type class does this as well.